# Single-use PRNG seedable with consecutive seeds

Tags: random

I need to make a pseudorandom number generator with a particular twist. Instead of generating numbers serially by using the seed from the previous generation for the new generation of a random number as it is usually done, I need a sequence of pseudorandom numbers generated in parallel from a consecutive sequence of seeds.

It would work like this, executed in parallel, each thread producing only a single number, with nothing shared or stored between threads:

```
thread #0: my_prng(1000) -> 1455191155 -> array[0]
thread #1: my_prng(1001) -> 2432152707 -> array[1]
thread #2: my_prng(1002) -> 185188134 -> array[2]
```

It's for generating image noise in parallel from a GPU (using OpenCL) so:

- it should be run fast enough, as in using just a few operations
- it shouldn't be cryptographically secure, it's just for graphics, it only needs to look about random
- low periods are just fine, even 2^24 would do
- it only needs to make 32-bit integers
- it shouldn't use any memory, no buffers, and not store anything in a variable other than the result (the resulting new seed if there were one would go unused anyway)
- it cannot rely on calls to rand() as it's not available in OpenCL or rely on any library
- it shouldn't loop to use serialness (for instance looping 60 times just to make the 60th number)
- it literally just needs to make a good pseudorandom number from a seed like 1000 that doesn't share a pattern with numbers made from adjacent seeds

None of the typical PRNG algorithms that I've tried could produce sequences from adjacent seeds that looked even remotely random, they're not meant to be seeded and used that way.

Comment: Do you have 64bit math?

Comment: Yes however it's possibly much slower so it would be best to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 32bit->32bit RNG, then period would be 2<sup>32</sup>, and with 2<sup>24</sup> in each stream you're limited to 2<sup>8</sup> streams.

Having said that, you might want to look into [LCG RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with following twist: implement fast skip-ahead as described in F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride," Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994).

Thus, you start with seed `1` and each consequent seed will just skip by 2<sup>24</sup> along the line

```
int32_t stream = 1 << 24;

rng.set_seed(int32_t seed) {
   rng.skip_ahead(seed*stream)
}
```

Thus, you'll guarantee to get non-overlapping streams covering your whole period

Code, which implements idea for 63bit generator is [here](https://github.com/Kri-Ol/LCG-PLE63/blob/master/std_LCG_PLE63.hpp)

UPDATE

F.Brown postulated skip-ahead is logarithmic in `N`, O(log<sub>2</sub>N).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, here's what I ended up with following that http://stackoverflow.com/a/35612914/1675589. What's with the 1<<24 thing though?

Comment: `What's with the 1<<24 thing though?` left shift to get 2^24

Comment: I know what that does, I mean what do you use `*stream` for?

Comment: Don't you want `stream` of random number per one thread? Maybe I misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 1):

Following Severin Pappadeux's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541729/single-use-prng-seedable-with-consecutive-seeds/35566841#35566841) I looked into fast skipping of LCGs and found that it is actually very simple to adapt the [MINSTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) algorithm for this using a simple [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

With MINSTD being `minstd(n+1) = 16807*minstd(n) mod 2147483647` we get `minstd(n+1) = 16807^n mod 2147483647`.

Here's my resulting algorithm in OpenCL:

```
int pow_mod(int base, uint expon, uint mod)
{
    int x = 1, power = base % mod;

    for (; expon > 0; expon >>= 1)
    {
        if (expon & 1)
            x = (x * power) % mod;

        power = (power * power) % mod;
    }

    return x;
}

uint rand16(uint pos)
{
    return pow_mod(16807, pos, 2147483647) >> 13 & 0xFFFF;
}

uint rand32(uint pos)
{
    return rand16(pos) << 16 | rand16(pos + 0x80000000);
}
```

MINSTD produces 31-bits (but no 2^31-1 value), however I found bad patterns in the 11 least significant bits, so I take 16 of the 20 good bits and make a good 32-bit random number out two of those.

`pos` would be a seed plus an offset, representing a position in the sequence of MINSTD outputs.